# Calculate partial derivative of multivariable function using the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \text { where } u = x^2 + y^2 + xz \text{ and } x = \sin t, y = e^t, z = t^3.$

The book claims the answer is $\sin2t + 2e^{2t} + 3t^2\sin t + t^3\cos t$.

I've got $(2 \sin t + t^3) \cos t + 2e^{t^2} + 3t^2 \sin t$.

Where is my mistake?

Using the `chain rule`, I've got that:

$$u'_t = u_xx_t + u_y y_t + u_zz_t = (2x + z)\cos t + 2y \cdot e^t + x 3t^2$$

Plug $x, y , z$ and finally get:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = (2\sin t + t^3)\cos t + 2 e^te^t + \sin t 3t^2 = \color{blue}{2\sin t \cos t + t^3 \cos t + 2e^{2t} + 3t^2\sin t}$.

I wonder there is my  mistake? thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $ \ \sin 2t \ = \ 2 \ \sin t \ \cos t \ ... $  (I tell students that there are three identities from trig that they should be sure to remember, if they forget everything else:  the Pythagorean Identity and the double-angle formulas for sine and cosine.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner So my answer is right?

Comment: The rest of what you wrote in blue agrees with the textbook answer.  What you wrote the first time is not quite correct because $ \ e^t  \cdot e^t \ \neq \ e^{t^2} \ . $  (Oh, and you should drop the prime on $ \ u_t \ , $ since you are already indicating differentiation by the subscript.)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Can you please explain my why $e^t\cdot e^t \ne e^{t^2}? \text{ Isn't } e^{t^2} = e^{t\cdot2} = e^{2t}?$

Comment: Remember that the rule for multiplying numbers which are exponents of the same base is $ \ a^p \cdot a^q \ = \ a^{p+q} \ , $ since we are multiplying a product of $ \ p \ $ "a" 's by a product of $ \ q \ $ "a" 's , so the number of "a" 's in the overall product is the _sum_ of all those "a" 's.  $ \ e^{t^2} \ $ is read as squaring the exponent $ \ t \ $ _first_ and then raising $ \ e \ $ to _that_ power, which will give quite a different value.  (For example, $ \ e^5 \cdot e^5 \ = \ e^{5+5} \ = \ e^{10} \ , $ **not** $ \ e^{5^2} \ = \ e^{25}  \ . ) $

Comment: Reading your second question again, I believe you are thinking of $ \ (e^t)^2 \ $ , which _is_ $ \ (e^t) \cdot (e^t) \ = \ e^{2t} \ . $  But $ \ e^{t^2} \ $ is taken to mean $ \ e^{(t^2)} \ . $  (So this is a notational issue to be aware of...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner You are great, thank you very much for everything!!!!

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful to you.